# Boost::Regex DOTALL flag

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

Is there a DOTALL matching flag for boost::regex? The documentation shows:

```
static const match_flag_type match_not_dot_newline;
static const match_flag_type match_not_dot_null;
```

but no mention of regular DOTALL.

I'm trying to match a python regular expression written as

```
re.compile(r'<a(.*?)</a>', re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `mod_s` [syntax_option_type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/syntax_option_type.html).  You can also use the inline modifier, `(?s)`.

Comment: @whatWhat: here's how to use the inline DOT-ALL modifier: `boost::regex e("(?s)<a(.*?)</a>");`