# Is there any way to have dot (.) match newline in C++ TR1 Regular Expressions?

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

I couldn't find anything regarding this on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727.aspx.

Maybe I could use `'[^]+'` to match everything but that seems like a hack?

Comment: Dot-all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712696/boostregex-dotall-flag

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Boost.Regex has a `mod_s` flag to make the dot match newlines, but *it's not part of the TR1 regex standard*. (and not available as a Microsoft extension either, as far as I can see)

As a workaround, you could use `[\s\S]` (which means match any whitespace or any non-whitespace).

Answer (score 9):

As C++ regular expressions appear to be based on ECMAScript regular expressions, the [answer to the recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines) about the same thing in JavaScript may help you.

`[^]` should work, but if you want something a little more clear and less hackish, you could try `(.|\n)`.

Answer (score 5):

One trick people use is a character class containing anything that is not the null character. The null character is expressed in hex. It looks something like this:

```
[^\x00]+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to a non-ECMA flavor of regular expression (there are a number of flags to control regext flavor). Any POSIX regex should, if I recall correctly, match a newline to `.`.

Comment: This works for example with `extended` regular expressions on Linux with gcc and on macOSX with Apple clang. Sadly, it does not work with Visual Studio, at least not with 2019 v16.8.0 that I tried. Therefore its not a generic solution.